# When i create module in dotnetnuke 6 just create following error

Tags: dotnetnuke

Error: pp is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dnn523\desktopmodules\dnnsamplemodule\web.config line 45) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dnn523\desktopmodules\dnnsamplemodule\web.config line 45) at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey) at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName) at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index) at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Compilation() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName) at System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureFirstTimeDirectoryInit(VirtualPath virtualDir) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at DotNetNuke.UI.ControlUtilities.LoadControl[T](TemplateControl containerControl, String ControlSrc) at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.WebFormsModuleControlFactory.CreateModuleControl(TemplateControl containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration) at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleControlFactory.LoadModuleControl(TemplateControl containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration) at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem should come from the web.config which is located in your module folder (i.e. dnnsamplemodule folder). If it doesn't contain any specific information, I recommand you to delete it.
More precisly, the problem is that some settings included in this web.config would override the settings of the web.config of your DNN root folder. Nevertheless, the current configuration of your computer doesn't allow this configuration.